# Setting Int Variable Between Classes in C#

Tags: c#

Very simplistic and basic code knowledge here. I have no schooling and am doing this for fun.

I have just begun making a simple Text RPG in C#, and it is my first attempt at using Classes that work together rather than using a single class that runs for a very large amount of lines.

I am trying to make take a Template Class that holds the Int Variables that my Battle System reads to make calculations:

```
namespace NatesFirstTextGame
{
    class EnemyTemplate
    {
        string Name;
        int Str;


        public int GetEnmStr()
        {
            return Str;
        }
        public void SetEnmStr(int a)
        {
            Str = a;
        }
        public string GetEnmName()
        {
            return Name;
        }
        public void SetEnmName(string a)
        {
            Name = a;
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to make individual Enemy Classes, that send their information to the Template Class for the Battle System to read:

```
namespace NatesFirstTextGame
{
    class Goose 
    {
        EnemyTemplate Enemy = new EnemyTemplate();

        public void GooseStats()
        {
            Enemy.SetEnmName("Goose");
            Enemy.SetEnmStr(1);

        }
    }
}
```

and am trying to run it like this:

```
namespace NatesFirstTextGame
{
    class GameDirectory
    {

        EnemyTemplate Enemy = new EnemyTemplate();
        Goose Goose = new Goose();
        Character Player = new Character();
        public void Game()
        {
            Goose.GooseStats();
            Console.WriteLine("Initiative check...");
            Console.WriteLine(Enemy.GetEnmDex() + " against " + 
            Player.GetDex());
            if(Player.GetDex() >= Enemy.GetEnmDex())
            {
                bool Initiative = true;
                Console.WriteLine("You have the first move.");

            }        
        }
    }
```

I've tried several ways of sending the Variables through, but I lack the knowledge to figure it out - when I run Goose to update the values in EnemyTemplate and then print the values, it all comes up blank as if nothing has happened. I've read up a bit on Inheritance and whatnot, but it's a little above my head to grasp at this point in time unless I settled in and really tried to understand, and I would rather have fun moving forward at a more basic level for now until I decide to take the next step in knowledge.

To sum it up: How can I send/update variables between classes in a way that would make the above possible?

EDIT: The two codes above are in SEPARATE files.

Comment: are the two codes above in one source file

Comment: How are you trying to print out the variables?  Also, I would recommend using a [constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constructors) rather than a bunch of set functions and public [properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/using-properties) with backing private fields rather than a bunch of get functions.

Comment: @StevenB. If i am honest I had(have) no proper idea in how to use a constructor, or what the rest of you said is or is done. I have begun reading up on all of it. 

I'm calling Goose to send the Stats over to EnemyTemplate, and then calling the Get functions in a class that has EnemyTemplate declared to try and display the values

Comment: @NathanialLake Please [edit] your question to include a full [mcve] which can be compiled and tested by others, which shows that the changed values in the `EnemyTemplate` object are not returned when you access them at the place where you need them.

Comment: @Progman hi there, I slimmed down the code and it should be compiler friendly.

Comment: @NathanialLake Your `Goose` class has it's own `EnemyTemplate` object it can change. This does not change the `EnemyTemplate` object in your `GameDirectory.Enemy` field. You are changing the values of one object and read the values from a different object.

Comment: @Progman Thanks! How would I read the values I am trying to change, or change the correct values?

Comment: @NathanialLake There are several solutions. One is: don't create the `EnemyTemplate` object inside the `Goose` object, but instead pass one `EnemyTemplate` as a method parameter into your method. Keep in mind that each `new EnemyTemplate()` is a new separate object. If you don't want that, don't do it.

Answer (score 0):

Your EnemyTemplate property "Enemy" in the Goose class is private so you need to declare public methods like GooseStats in the Goose class to call public methods of Enemy an return their results. For example your Goose class can be modified like this.

```
namespace NatesFirstTextGame
{
    class Goose 
    {
        EnemyTemplate Enemy = new EnemyTemplate();

        public void GooseStats()
        {
            Enemy.SetEnmName("Goose");
            Enemy.SetEnmStr(1);
            Enemy.SetEnmDex(1);
            Enemy.SetEnmConHP(1);
        }

        public string GetEnemyEnmName(){
            return Enemy.GetEnmName();
        }

        public int GetEnemyEnmStr()
        {
            return Enemy.GetEnmStr();
        }
    }
}
```

Then use it like this.

```
namespace NatesFirstTextGame
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Goose goose = new Goose();
            goose.GooseStats();
            goose.GetEnemyEnmName();
            Console.WriteLine(goose.GetEnemyEnmName());
            Console.WriteLine(goose.GetEnemyEnmStr());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you give me a brief example? I dont have much depth of understanding yet, so reading this makes some sense but I dont know how to implement it.

Comment: I tried this quickly this morning and it didnt seem to work - i updated my question a bit. I will try more intently today after work in about 10hrs

Comment: Please compare my code with yours. In my Program class I did not declare an EnemyTemplate object because the Goose class has its own EnemyTemplate object. In your GameDirectory class you have an EnemyTemplate object called "Enemy" and you have another EnemyTemplate object in your Goose object. These two objects are stored in two different places in memory. Your problem is you are setting data for the first object and retrieving data from the second object.

Comment: Thank you! Very informative. I will work on it when I get back home.